# Hide div off bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a div:

```
<div id="hide-me">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

How can I use CSS to position this off the bottom of the screen, I later plan to animate it up from the bottom).

Comment: You can use `margin-bottom:-999px;`

Comment: A lot of the answers here position don't take into account that you mentioned that you wanted to animate the `#hide-me` div from the bottom. If a 2s animation is applied then the results will be drastically different for a `#hide-me` div just outside of the viewport and one that is placed something like `-9999px` outside of the viewport.

Comment: Here is an example of what I mentioned above: http://jsfiddle.net/cwwx596x/. Adjust the bottom property where noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `position:absolute`

```css
#hide-me {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -99999px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hide-me">
  <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#hide-me {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
margin-bottom:-999px;
```

for relatively positioned div

or for absolute positioned div use

```
bottom:-999px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning:

```
#hide-me
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

But remember to set the height of your html & body element to 100%!

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```